# Using result of a SQL case to compare and return another case

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to compare the result of a sum which returns an amount, by using a case that would return the result of this comparison:

```
SELECT u.name, u.account,
    sum (case u.account
        when t.sent_to then t.quantity * -1
    else t.quantity end) as quantity_sent,
        case when quantity_sent > u.available then 'YES'
            else 'NO' end as analysis_result
from users as u inner join trans as t
on u.account in (t.sent_to, t.received_by)
group by u.name, u.account;
```

Whenever I call quantity_sent back, I get an "Invalid column name quantity_sent". Is there any other way I can use the result on this newly created column to compare inside a case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
SELECT 
u.name, u.account,
SUM (
    CASE u.account
        WHEN t.sent_to THEN t.quantity * -1
        ELSE t.quantity 
    END
) AS quantity_sent,
CASE 
    WHEN SUM (
        CASE u.account
            WHEN t.sent_to then t.quantity * -1
            ELSE t.quantity 
        END ) > u.available THEN 'YES'
        ELSE 'NO' 
END as analysis_result
FROM users as u 
INNER JOIN trans as t
ON u.account in (t.sent_to, t.received_by)
GROUP BY u.name, u.account;
```

Comment: When I do the following it says that none of the other fields (quantity, sent_to, received_by) is contained in an aggregate function or group by.

Comment: Upvoted as it showed me an example of repeating the subquery. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, SUM was missing in the script.

Answer (score 1):

You need to repeat the expression or use a subquery:

```
select name, account, quantity_sent,
       (case when quantity_sent > u.available then 'YES'
             else 'NO'
        end) as analysis_result
from (select u.name, u.account,
             sum(case u.account
                     when t.sent_to then t.quantity * -1
                     else t.quantity
                 end) as quantity_sent
      from users u inner join
           trans t
           on u.account in (t.sent_to, t.received_by)
      group by u.name, u.account
     ) u;
```

This is part of the general rule in SQL that you cannot re-use a column alias in the `SELECT` where it is defined.  There is a simple reason for this:  SQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of the expressions in the `SELECT`.

Comment: There was an extra comma between "as quantity_sent, from users..", after I fixed that, I'm getting "invalid column name on u.available" - that's a valid column

Comment: I"ve repeated the expression instead of using a subquery. That didn't lead to an invalid column name. Thanks!

Comment: @LucasNeto . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?